# How do I add items to a list? using only onsubmit <form>

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit

I am creating a to do list using Javascript/HTML. How do I add text input to a list using onsubmit in a `<form>`. This is what I got so far.

```
<h1>To-Do List</h1>

<form onsubmit= "return addItem(document.getElementById(list), inputText)"> ` 
    <input type="text" id="inputItem" placeholder="Enter a Task">
    <input type="submit">

</form>

<ul id="list">

</ul>

<script 
// adds Task to list

function addItem(list, inputText) {
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.innerText = "inputText";

    list.appendChild(listItem)

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. get the list correctly ('list'), not (list)
2. Pass the field to the function, not some string - you CAN pass 'inputField' but then you also need `var value = document.getElementById(inputField).value` and have `"return addItem('list', 'inputItem')"`
3. return false or use preventDefault to not submit the form for real

```js
function addItem(list, inputField) { 
  var list = document.getElementById(list);
  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  listItem.innerText = inputField.value; // passed the field. 
  list.appendChild(listItem);
  return false; // stop submission
}
```

```html
<h1>To-Do List</h1>

<form onsubmit="return addItem('list', this.inputItem)"> 
  <input type="text" id="inputItem" placeholder="Enter a Task">
  <input type="submit">

</form>

<ul id="list">

</ul>
```

Unobtrusively:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit = function() {
    var list = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-list')); // only needed if more than one form or list
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var inputItem = this.inputItem;
    listItem.innerText = inputItem.value;
    list.appendChild(listItem);
    inputItem.select();
    inputItem.focus();
    return false; // stop submission
  }
  document.getElementById("inputItem").focus();
}
```

```html
<h1>To-Do List</h1>

<form id="form1" data-list="list">
  <input type="text" id="inputItem" placeholder="Enter a Task">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much. I understand it much better. I fixed the code and even add a feature where it clears the input text after submission. But it doesn't work well. do you happen to know a better way. this is how I tried doing it.                        var inputItem = document.getElementById("inputItem");                             
                                         inputItem.focus();
                                                       inputItem.select();

Comment: Thanks once again.

Comment: would it also be possible to just replace the selected input text with an empty string.

Comment: `inputItem.value="";    inputItem.focus();`

Comment: See my second code for the select/focus version then you do not need to clear the entry and you allow the user to add a similar item

Comment: haha I just figured that out right before loading the page. I appreciate your help.

Comment: How could I add something before and after every list Item?

Comment: You mean `listItem.innerHTML = ‘<b>New item: </b>’+inputItem.value+’.’;`